# the archive may be corrupt or unreadable

Tags: iphone, xcode

[image][image]I was trying to crate an archive to upload the app for app store. But when i was going to create a archive by choosing correct provisioning (distribution for app store)in code signing identity(in project and targets also) along same bundle ID than, first of all archive do not shown in organizer although xcode says it's succeeded. Secondly when i go to folder /library/developer/xcode/archives than, it do contain .xarchive. On double click, it says "the archive may be corrupt or unreadable". How to get out from this problem .. please help out.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this too for a bit, and I found that downgrading cocoapods from version 1.10.0 to 1.9.3 fixed the corrupt archive issues above. The command I used:

```
gem install cocoapods -v '<= 1.9.3' -n /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: This helped me a lot!! I couldn't see my archive in the Organizer view before this, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,get the build from the Product tree in **Xcode** and create a new folder with name"**Payload**" and keep that build in that and compressed it and rename extension to "**.ipa**".That will ask for ipa,use ipa then.Try this

Comment: you can upload ipa to app store also,is kind of compressed file.

Comment: thorugh organizer or application loader and how please describe procedure. I guess it's through app loader.

Comment: should i keep the name of .ipa as payload?

Comment: application loader is not accessing the itune connect id and password. After some time it says "information you sign-in is wrong" but on safari same password and id is running fine.

Comment: activity indicator keeps revolving for 15 mins. I doubled check my id and password its running fine on safari.

Comment: create the clean build again,restart xcode and then try.Make sure your itunes profile must be created and status must be waiting for upload.

Comment: yes! my app status is ready to upload. I restarted xcode even my mac and build again... but.. :( what can be the prominent reason for not accessing my account if itune connect.

Comment: Application loader  access credentials  through key chain , may be some thing wrong with certificates,cross check.